# Is it possible to set the Items property of a WPF ComboBox in a style?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a form in WPF that requires a number of Yes/No comboboxes, databound to boolean properties on the viewmodel.  As such, the item list is static.  Rather than repeat it for every combobox, I was hoping to achieve this with a style; something like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="trueFalseCombo" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">
        <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Tag"/>
        <Setter Property="Items">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="{StaticResource True}">Yes</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="{StaticResource False}">No</ComboBoxItem>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But I receive the "Value is set more than once" error.  I was thinking I needed to wrap in the items into some sort of collection container, but I couldn't figure out what.  Is this even possible to do?

I realize I can make a simple custom control for this, but if it's not possible in a style I wanted a better understanding of why.

Comment: If you're using MVVM, then don't use the `Items` collection.  Bind the `ItemsSource` to a collection containing `true` and `false` values.  You can set an `ItemsSource` binding in a style, though I'm not sure it's worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `ItemsSource` property instead of `Items`. There is also no need for `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` if you use a collection of boolean values.

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...

<Style x:Key="trueFalseCombo" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
        <Setter.Value>
            <x:Array Type="sys:Boolean">
                <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                <sys:Boolean>False</sys:Boolean>
            </x:Array>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In order to display Yes and No instead of True and False, you may use an ItemTemplate like this:

```
<Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="No"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Ah perfect, setting the ItemsSource to an x:Array is what I needed, thanks.  In my case I can't use a direct list of booleans because our spec calls for the combos to read Yes/No instead of True/False, but this got me going. Cheers